# Modificar estilo en HTML segun una Condición

Tags: java, html

Tengo el siguiente codigo, y mi intencion es que si la fechaActual es mayor al campo se muestre en rojo , sino en verde()por ello he creado dos clases en el css , pero codificarlo...
Gracias a todos.

```css
.noRed{
    color:green;
    
}
.red{
     color: red;
    
    
}
```

```html
                   if (rs.next()){
           java.util.Date fechaNuevoPedido=rs.getDate("FECHA_REQ_SIG_PEDIDO");

                  
                  <tr>
                      <%  Date myDate = new Date();

                        if (myDate.after(fechaNuevoPedido)){
                         int cont=1;
                         }else {
                            int cont=-1
                         }
                          
                          
                          %>
                    <td>Fecha estimada nuevo pedido:</td>
                    <td><label class=<%if(cont=1){%>"red" for="coments"><B><%=rs.getString("FECHA_REQ_SIG_PEDIDO")%></B></label></td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: Hola Iron man, puedes editar el codigo para que tenga una adecuada indentación (y no es necesario el snippet de codigo ya que no puede ejecutar Java) Un saludo

Comment: Te recomiendo que no uses scriptlets en tus JSP, **nunca** es una buena idea mezclar código Java con HTML/XML

Comment: Nunca es buena idea? A que te refieres? Y que alternativa me sugieres? Lo siento soy un poco novato... @PabloLozano

Comment: @IronMan Puedes encontrar bastantes [comentarios](http://www.javamexico.org/foros/java_enterprise/jsp_sin_scriplets#comment-7687) que desaconsejan su uso, y [preguntas en SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188706/how-to-avoid-using-scriptlets-in-my-jsp-page) sobre el tema (cómo evitarlos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el if tienes que poner un doble igual de comparacion, en lugar de solo uno de asignación.

```
<td>
 <label class=<%if(cont==1){%>"red"<%} else {%> "noRed" <%}%> for="coments"><B><%=rs.getString("FECHA_REQ_SIG_PEDIDO")%></B></label>
</td>
```

en las condiciones parece que buscas algo como lo que te pongo encima, si tu condicion es 1 la clase es 'red' sino la clase sería 'noRed'